MegaRAID LSI SAS-9266-8i no RAID6 available after flashing firmware
Dear Good People of serverfault.com,
I flash my MegaRAID LSI SAS-9266-8i RAID controller with latest Mega Firmware found here broadcom.com using storcli64. Everything went fine However, it seems there is no RAID6 available. Not sure what went wrong but this is what i did:
Code:
storcli64 /c0 download file=mr2208fw.rom noverchk
storcli64 /c0 set factory defaults
storcli64 /c0 restart

Also I search the forums and tried to flash the controller using dos and MegaREC without any luck.
here is the output of “storcli64 /c0 show all”
CLI Version = 007.1017.0000.0000 May 10, 2019
Operating system = Linux 6.6.7-d-allmods
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = None


Basics :
======
Controller = 0
Model = LSI MegaRAID SAS 9266-8i
Serial Number = 
Current Controller Date/Time = 03/10/2024, 12:04:56
Current System Date/time = 03/10/2024, 12:04:56
SAS Address = 500605b005283010
PCI Address = 00:04:00:00
Mfg Date = 00/00/00
Rework Date = 00/00/00
Revision No = 


Version :
=======
Firmware Package Build = 23.34.0-0019
Firmware Version = 3.460.114-6464
Bios Version = 5.50.03.0_4.17.08.00_0x06110200
WebBIOS Version = 6.1-76-e_76-Rel
Preboot CLI Version = 05.07-00:#%00011
NVDATA Version = 2.1507.04-0157
Boot Block Version = 2.05.00.00-0010
Bootloader Version = 07.26.26.219
Driver Name = megaraid_sas
Driver Version = 07.725.01.00-rc1


Bus :
===
Vendor Id = 0x1000
Device Id = 0x5B
SubVendor Id = 0x1000
SubDevice Id = 0x9266
Host Interface = PCI-E
Device Interface = SAS-6G
Bus Number = 4
Device Number = 0
Function Number = 0


Pending Images in Flash :
=======================
Image name = No pending images


Status :
======
Controller Status = Needs Attention
Memory Correctable Errors = 0
Memory Uncorrectable Errors = 0
ECC Bucket Count = 0
Any Offline VD Cache Preserved = No
BBU Status = NA
PD Firmware Download in progress = No
Support PD Firmware Download = No
Lock Key Assigned = No
Failed to get lock key on bootup = No
Lock key has not been backed up = No
Bios was not detected during boot = No
Controller must be rebooted to complete security operation = No
A rollback operation is in progress = No
At least one PFK exists in NVRAM = Yes
SSC Policy is WB = No
Controller has booted into safe mode = No
Controller shutdown required = No


Supported Adapter Operations :
============================
Rebuild Rate = Yes
CC Rate = Yes
BGI Rate  = Yes
Reconstruction Rate = Yes
Patrol Read Rate = Yes
Alarm Control = Yes
Cluster Support = No
BBU = NA
Spanning = Yes
Dedicated Hot Spare = Yes
Revertible Hot Spares = Yes
Foreign Config Import = Yes
Self Diagnostic = Yes
Allow Mixed Redundancy on Array = No
Global Hot Spares = Yes
Deny SCSI Passthrough = No
Deny SMP Passthrough = No
Deny STP Passthrough = No
Support more than 8 Phys = Yes
FW and Event Time in GMT = No
Support Enhanced Foreign Import = Yes
Support Enclosure Enumeration = Yes
Support Allowed Operations = Yes
Abort CC on Error = Yes
Support Multipath = Yes
Support Odd & Even Drive count in RAID1E = No
Support Security = No
Support Config Page Model = Yes
Support the OCE without adding drives = Yes
Support EKM = No
Snapshot Enabled = No
Support PFK = Yes
Support PI = No
Support Ld BBM Info = No
Support Shield State = Yes
Block SSD Write Disk Cache Change = Yes
Support Suspend Resume BG ops = Yes
Support Emergency Spares = Yes
Support Set Link Speed = Yes
Support Boot Time PFK Change = No
Support JBOD = Yes
Disable Online PFK Change = No
Support Perf Tuning = Yes
Support SSD PatrolRead = Yes
Real Time Scheduler = Yes
Support Reset Now = Yes
Support Emulated Drives = Yes
Headless Mode = Yes
Dedicated HotSpares Limited = No
Point In Time Progress = Yes
Extended LD = No
Support Uneven span  = No
Support Config Auto Balance = No
Support Maintenance Mode = No
Support Diagnostic results = No
Support Ext Enclosure = No
Support Sesmonitoring = No
Support SecurityonJBOD = No
Support ForceFlash = No
Support DisableImmediateIO = No
Support LargeIOSupport = No
Support DrvActivityLEDSetting = Yes
Support FlushWriteVerify = No
Support CPLDUpdate = No
Support ForceTo512e = Yes
Support discardCacheDuringLDDelete = No
Support JBOD Write cache = No
Support Large QD Support = No
Support Ctrl Info Extended = No
Support IButton less = No
Support AES Encryption Algorithm = No
Support Encrypted MFC = No
Support Snapdump = No
Support Force Personality Change = No
Support Dual Fw Image = No
Support PSOC Update = No
Support Secure Boot = No
Support Clear Snapdump = No
Support Debug Queue = No
Support Least Latency Mode = Yes
Support OnDemand Snapdump = No


Supported PD Operations :
=======================
Force Online = Yes
Force Offline = Yes
Force Rebuild = Yes
Deny Force Failed = No
Deny Force Good/Bad = No
Deny Missing Replace = No
Deny Clear = No
Deny Locate = No
Support Power State = Yes
Set Power State For Cfg = No
Support T10 Power State = No
Support Temperature = Yes
NCQ = Yes
Support Max Rate SATA = No
Support Degraded Media = No
Support Parallel FW Update = No
Support Drive Crypto Erase = No
Support SSD Wear Gauge = No


Supported VD Operations :
=======================
Read Policy = No
Write Policy = No
IO Policy = No
Access Policy = Yes
Disk Cache Policy = Yes
Reconstruction = Yes
Deny Locate = No
Deny CC = No
Allow Ctrl Encryption = No
Enable LDBBM = No
Support FastPath = Yes
Performance Metrics = Yes
Power Savings = No
Support Powersave Max With Cache = No
Support Breakmirror = No
Support SSC WriteBack = No
Support SSC Association = No
Support VD Hide = No
Support VD Cachebypass = No
Support VD discardCacheDuringLDDelete = No
Support VD Scsi Unmap = No


Advanced Software Option :
========================

-------------------------------------------------
Adv S/W Opt        Time Remaining           Mode 
-------------------------------------------------
MegaRAID FastPath  Unlimited                -    
MegaRAID RAID5     Unlimited                -    
Cache Offload      Unlimited (Unsupported)  -    
-------------------------------------------------

Safe ID =  K6DSL42AFNLL9M7X2VIRL5LUWTXWC25GB62LK4IZ

HwCfg :
=====
ChipRevision =  C1
BatteryFRU = N/A
Front End Port Count = 0
Backend Port Count = 8
BBU = Absent
Alarm = On
Serial Debugger = Present
NVRAM Size = 32KB
Flash Size = 16MB
On Board Memory Size = 0MB
CacheVault Flash Size = NA
TPM = Absent
Upgrade Key = Absent
On Board Expander = Absent
Temperature Sensor for ROC = Present
Temperature Sensor for Controller = Absent
Upgradable CPLD = Absent
Upgradable PSOC = Absent
Current Size of CacheCade (GB) = 0
Current Size of FW Cache (MB) = 0
ROC temperature(Degree Celsius) = 89


Policies :
========

Policies Table :
==============

------------------------------------------------
Policy                          Current Default 
------------------------------------------------
Predictive Fail Poll Interval   300 sec         
Interrupt Throttle Active Count 16              
Interrupt Throttle Completion   50 us           
Rebuild Rate                    30 %    30%     
PR Rate                         30 %    30%     
BGI Rate                        30 %    30%     
Check Consistency Rate          30 %    30%     
Reconstruction Rate             30 %    30%     
Cache Flush Interval            4s              
------------------------------------------------

Flush Time(Default) = 4s
Drive Coercion Mode = 1GB
Auto Rebuild = On
Battery Warning = Off
ECC Bucket Size = 15
ECC Bucket Leak Rate (hrs) = 24
Restore Hot Spare on Insertion = Off
Expose Enclosure Devices = On
Maintain PD Fail History = On
Reorder Host Requests = On
Auto detect BackPlane = SGPIO/i2c SEP
Load Balance Mode = Auto
Security Key Assigned = Off
Disable Online Controller Reset = Off
Use drive activity for locate = Off


Boot :
====
BIOS Enumerate VDs = 1
Stop BIOS on Error = On
Delay during POST = 0
Spin Down Mode = None
Enable Ctrl-R = No
Enable Web BIOS = Yes
Enable PreBoot CLI = Yes
Enable BIOS = Yes
Max Drives to Spinup at One Time = 2
Maximum number of direct attached drives to spin up in 1 min = 0
Delay Among Spinup Groups (sec) = 12
Allow Boot with Preserved Cache = Off


High Availability :
=================
Topology Type = None
Cluster Permitted = No
Cluster Active = No


Defaults :
========
Phy Polarity = 0
Phy PolaritySplit = 0
Strip Size = 64 KB
Write Policy = WT
Read Policy = No Read Ahead
Cache When BBU Bad = Off
Cached IO = Off
VD PowerSave Policy = Controller Defined
Default spin down time (mins) = 30
Coercion Mode = None
ZCR Config = Unknown
Max Chained Enclosures = 2
Direct PD Mapping = No
Restore Hot Spare on Insertion = No
Expose Enclosure Devices = Yes
Maintain PD Fail History = Yes
Zero Based Enclosure Enumeration = No
Disable Puncturing = No
EnableLDBBM = No
DisableHII = No
Un-Certified Hard Disk Drives = Allow
SMART Mode = Mode 6
Enable LED Header = No
LED Show Drive Activity = Yes
Dirty LED Shows Drive Activity = No
EnableCrashDump = No
Disable Online Controller Reset = No
Treat Single span R1E as R10 = No
Power Saving option = Enabled
TTY Log In Flash = Yes
Auto Enhanced Import = No
BreakMirror RAID Support = No
Disable Join Mirror = No
Enable Shield State = Yes
Time taken to detect CME = 60 sec


Capabilities :
============
Supported Drives = SAS, SATA
RAID Level Supported = RAID0, RAID1(2 or more drives), RAID5, RAID00, RAID10(2 or more drives per span), RAID50
Enable JBOD = No
Mix in Enclosure = Allowed
Mix of SAS/SATA of HDD type in VD = Allowed
Mix of SAS/SATA of SSD type in VD = Not Allowed
Mix of SSD/HDD in VD = Not Allowed
SAS Disable = No
Max Arms Per VD = 16
Max Spans Per VD = 8
Max Arrays = 16
Max VD per array = 16
Max Number of VDs = 16
Max Parallel Commands = 256
Max SGE Count = 60
Max Data Transfer Size = 8192 sectors
Max Strips PerIO = 20
Max Configurable CacheCade Size(GB) = 0
Max Transportable DGs = 0
Enable Snapdump = No
Enable SCSI Unmap = Yes
FDE Drive Mix Support = No
Min Strip Size = 8 KB
Max Strip Size = 64 KB


Scheduled Tasks :
===============
Consistency Check Reoccurrence = 168 hrs
Next Consistency check launch = 03/16/2024, 03:00:00
Patrol Read Reoccurrence = 168 hrs
Next Patrol Read launch = 03/09/2024, 03:00:00
Battery learn Reoccurrence = NA
Next Battery Learn = NA
OEMID = AVAGO

Physical Drives = 8

PD LIST :
=======

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model            Sp Type 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
62:0      9 UGood -  3.637 TB SAS  HDD Y   N  512B ST4000NM0043     D  -    
62:1     10 UGood -  3.637 TB SAS  HDD Y   N  512B ST4000NM0043     D  -    
62:2      8 UGood -  3.637 TB SAS  HDD Y   N  512B ST4000NM0043     U  -    
62:3     14 UGood -  3.637 TB SAS  HDD Y   N  512B ST4000NM0043     D  -    
62:4     11 UGood -  3.637 TB SAS  HDD Y   N  512B ST4000NM0043     D  -    
62:5     12 UGood -  3.637 TB SAS  HDD Y   N  512B ST4000NM0043     D  -    
62:6     13 UGood -  3.637 TB SAS  HDD Y   N  512B ST4000NM0043     D  -    
62:7     15 UGood -  3.637 TB SAS  HDD Y   N  512B ST4000NM0043     D  -    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

EID=Enclosure Device ID|Slt=Slot No.|DID=Device ID|DG=DriveGroup
DHS=Dedicated Hot Spare|UGood=Unconfigured Good|GHS=Global Hotspare
UBad=Unconfigured Bad|Onln=Online|Offln=Offline|Intf=Interface
Med=Media Type|SED=Self Encryptive Drive|PI=Protection Info
SeSz=Sector Size|Sp=Spun|U=Up|D=Down|T=Transition|F=Foreign
UGUnsp=Unsupported|UGShld=UnConfigured shielded|HSPShld=Hotspare shielded
CFShld=Configured shielded|Cpybck=CopyBack|CBShld=Copyback Shielded
UBUnsp=UBad Unsupported

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
